# How to re-register an Excel addin after its name has changed?

Tags: excel, vba, vb6

I been trying to develop a COM Add In for Excel Custom Task Pane(CTP).
The environment will be win10, Office 2016, VB6 SP2.
During the painful debugging stage, I found some issues, just for your reference.

1. The actually working registry will be HKCU, not the HKLM one.
   [image: 1. The actually working registry will be HKCU, not the HKLM one.]
2. After OCX been created, it have to register by regsvr32, and OCX(DLL) register action only accept once for Excel COM Addin.
   Excel In will record Project Name In "COM Add In" with the registered GUID, and it can't change.
   That means if you due to some reason to delete the first times registered OCX of the same project name, the Excel COM Addin will record it, even though you search the GUID of the first times registered in registry, and delete it. The Excel COM Addin won't change the GUID!
   Or maybe Master can provide some idea of this.
   [image]

As above for your reference.

Comment: Can you please clarify what your actual question is?

Comment: @StayOnTarget Thanks for your question, first, I just record the Excel COM Add In design issue, since I try to find out solution "Excel COM Add In Object is nothing", even to check a lots of web article, but can't find. finally, I found the GUID key is different between registry and COM Add In, therefore I just remark it for all who needs it. second, I don't know why the Excel COM Add In can't refresh, even though I re-register it by "regsvr32", but can't work, if anyone knew, please advise, thanks!

Comment: Not clear from the descriptions, but perhaps binary compatibility needs to be set in the project options?  So that a recompile of the control can be referenced by the Excel reference without having to refresh/reestablish the reference?

Comment: @MarkL Yes, the VB6 Complied Compatibility must set as the latest version complied, otherwise, the GUID will be re-generated.
But what if any situation that may need to delete the original complied file, the GUID will be changed and different with the Excel COM AddIn.
That's the purpose I put this REMARK here for anyone which don't know why "Excel COM Add In Object is nothing"